# Files deleted when updating to CentOS 6.6

Tags: linux, centos6, selinux

I recently ran yum update to upgrade a web server from CentOS 6.5 to 6.6. The update ran successfully, but for some reason all the website files (stored under /srv) were deleted. Other files such as /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf were untouched.

It wasn't a big deal, as they were all backed up, but restoring the file permission settings I had was a bit of a pain. I was using ACLs to control permissions—this is the only thing I can think of that might have caused it (something to do with SELinux?). I tried Google, but no luck.

Does anyone have any idea why this might have happened? If possible I'd prefer to avoid it happening again in the future. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you disk partition was `/dev/sda4` you can use following command for recovery all deleted or lost files,

```
 extundelete /dev/sda4 --restore-all
```